# Retrofit возвращает пустой объект

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, retrofit

Для получения JSONObject с сайта раньше использовал OkHttp. Хочу поменять на Retrofit, но он возвращает пустой объект

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ApiService service;
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MAIN_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    final Call<JSONObject> call = service.takeList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response)
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "------onResponse---------" + response.body().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t)
        {
            ...
        }
    });
}

public interface ApiService
{
    @GET("get.php")
    Call<JSONObject> takeList();
}
```

В логах следующее:

```
W/MainActivity: ------onResponse---------{}
```

Здесь же попробовал запрос через OkHttp

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(MAIN_URL + "get.php")
                        .build();
                okhttp3.Call call = client.newCall(request);
                okhttp3.Response response = call.execute();

                Log.w(TAG, "=============OK==================" + response.body().string());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

И все нормально работает. В логах:

```
W/MainActivity: =============OK=================={"error":"Invalid type"}
```

(Ошибка из-за того, что не передаю параметры. Пока пытаюсь хоть такой вариант ответа получить от Retrofit-a)

Answer (score 3):

А зачем вы указываете `JSONObject` в качестве объекта для десериалазации? Ретрофит пытается его `десериализовать` ища переменные в классе `JSONObject` в пришедших данных и это будет безуспешно.

Замените для начала `Call<JSONObject>` на `Call<String>` (и сопутствующее с ним) и попробуйте получить данные, как увидите строку, создайте `Generic` класс для Вашего `JSON`.

**upd**

Создайте класс:

```
public class ResponseData {
    private String error;

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error
    }
}
```

Используйте как `Call<ResponseData>`, туда вам будет падать ошибка, Также. добавьте логи, что бы видеть ответ от сервера, до того как он будет десериализован.

Для этого, добавьте библиотеку

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
}
```

И соотвественно код на вашем примере

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
    ApiService service;
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MAIN_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build()) //добавляем измененный httpClient
            .build();
...........
}
```

После чего, смотрите в `LogCat`, когда будете получать валидные данные, Расширяйте, ваш класс `ResponseData` для десерализации.

Comment: Вот тут гайд, который мне в свое время очень помог понять принципы https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Строку не хочет принимать. Отрабатывает метод onFailure. В логах:  `E/MainActivity: ---------onFailure------Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: @Turkovsky обновил ответ